# vim in Cygwin replaces first character with 'g' on opening a file

Tags: vim, cygwin, vi, xterm

I use vim in Cygwin terminal. It was working fine. Recently, I added a package in Cygwin which caused update of vim and some other components. Now when I open any file in vim, the first character in the file gets replaced with character 'g'.

I tried removing .vimrc and all files in .vim folder in my home folder. But the problem persists.

To understand the problem, I opened a file using 'vim -E'. On opening, I see the following at the bottom of the window:

```
Entering Ex mode. Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:]11;rgb:0000/0000/0000\
```

The key sequence rgb in vim would replace the first character with 'g'.

This problem seems to be related to xterm configuration. But I cannot figure it out.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update:**

I added the following line in ~/.vimrc :

colorscheme default

This solved the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Taking your suspicion, I changed cygwin terminal to vt100 (right click title bar -> Options -> Terminal) and saw the problem go away.

Comment: This poster had the same issue and solved their problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31802751/4390071

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is. But I tried to reinstall **7.4.752-1** version of **vim** and **vim-common**, this problem disappeared. Hope this help you!

Updated on 20150806: **upgrade** to 7.4.808-1 will fix the problem!

Comment: I had the same problem with 7.4.764-1 and it disappeared in 7.4.808-1

Comment: upgrading to 7.4.808-1 fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

problem with escape sequences when restoring the cursor position from a file .viminfo by older xterm clients
my solution - insert in .vimrc :

```
set noek
function Mode()
set ek
endfunction

au InsertEnter * call Mode()
au InsertChange * call Mode()
au InsertLeave * call Mode()
```

Comment: Thank y♂u sir for solving my problem, after I searching for one hour!