# Why vim is changing first letter to g after opening a file

Tags: vim, cygwin, bash

When I open a file, eg `vim .bashrc`, vim opens the file and change the first letter to `g`. What I see is the following:

```
g To the extent possible under law, the author(s) have dedicated all
# copyright and related and neighboring rights to this software to the
...
```

I change `g` back to `#`, but after loading the file its again changed. Happens with multiple files.

Last things I have done was: installig `gcc` and `make`.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:
My .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set number
set tabstop=4
syntax on
```

Comment: Try to track down the offender with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx

Comment: My first suspect would be an autocommand for the filetype(s) you are opening. An error in your .vimrc would not show after reloading the file. Take a look at your $VIMRUNTIME\ftplugin folder for the filetype you are loading and for any change to that filetype plugin.

Comment: @n.m. Check question#EDIT I added my .vimrc.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Variable $VIMRUNTIME is empty :(

Comment: Does it happen when you start as `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: Try `vim -D filename` to see where extra commands are coming from.

Comment: Use `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` from within vim.

Comment: I have located ftplugin folder, but I dont think that'll help, since this issue occurs on files with various extensions and even on files with no extension at all.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers `vim -u NONE` wil start vim with no file open in main screen with no "g" present. I dont even know where I should look for it, since you dont have file open...

Comment: @cdarke How can I see the extra commands with that debug? When I run the debug I dont see the content of a file, I see only a command line of debug...

Comment: What Vim version is this? And can you try with the latest version?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775203/vim-in-cygwin-replaces-first-character-with-g-on-opening-a-file

Comment: Possibly related (if you're using mobaXterm) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/_Q26KGKB5nk/jQmUmbbm-kIJ

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt vim --version
`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 29 2015 18:44:34)
Použité záplaty (~applied patches): 1-764`
I believe its the latest.

Comment: @arenaq I believe this issue is fixed with a newer Version. (7.4.770) If not, please report back to vim_dev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it appers to be a vim [issue](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/45535). So far I gathered only two solutions:

- Reinstall to older version of vim. i reinstalled to 7.4.752-1 and bug is gone.
- Change cygwin terminal to anyone but "xterm*" (right-click on title bar -> Options... -> Terminal -> Type)

Comment: Didn't have a problem with Ubuntu 16.04. After updating to Ubuntu 18.04.1 (VIM 8.0.1453), it started happening while connected remotely with SecureCRT (an old version -- 7.3), although in my case it was changing the first character to 'p' and ringing the bell. None of the .vimrc tweaks worked for me. Changing the terminal type from "xterm" to "linux" in the shell fixed it. (I tested it with `export TERM=linux`, then made it "permanent" by updating the terminal settings in SecureCRT.)

Answer (score 18):

I had the exact same problem

I found out it was a bug in my ssh client (mobaXterm).

Updating (to mobaXterm 'personal edition v9.1') resolved the issue.

Comment: Exactly the same bug on an old version of the same great ssh client.

Answer (score 12):

I am using vim on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 via MobaXterm version 7.7.  This is an older version of MobaXterm that supports command-line-settable terminal background colors.

The following change to my .bash_profile solved this problem for me:

```
# Fix for Vim 8.0 bug that stomps on line 1 char 1:
export TERM=linux
```

Answer (score 8):

Strange enough, but it works for me. I created a ~/.vimrc file:

```
syntax on   
set background=dark
```

The 2nd option disable the bug.

Comment: Solved here too. Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

For me, I traced the issue down to the following line:

```
set nocompatible
```

It is found in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim`, which is included from `/etc/vim/vimrc` with the line `runtime! debian.vim`

Comment: This change worked for me -- but I'm not sure what I'm losing by switching to "set compatible" -- because doing this supposedly suppresses vim features that were improvements over raw vi...

Comment: In the end, I chose to leave in "set nocompatible" and change my terminal from xterm to ansi, e.g.: export TERM=ansi.  This also works.

Comment: @bearvarine I didn't lose anything meaningful by this

Answer (score 1):

make sure you dont set the visual bell in your .vimrc

```
set visualbell
```

in case you have it then just delete it :)

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing was happening to me! It wasn't occurring in gvim, so I thought maybe something was going on in my .vimrc. I zeroed-out my .vimrc but it was still happening. Only when I completely deleted my .vimrc did this behavior stop. As suggested,I rolled back to an older version (7.3.1152-1) with cygwin setup and that fixed it. I did not have to change any terminal settings, however. It makes sense because I updated cygwin yesterday, when I started seeing the errant g's.

Answer (score 0):

I am on ArchLinux. vim 8.0.0987-1 always decreases a number upon opening a file (as if xtrl+x pressed). Downgrade to 8.0.0722-1 fixed the issue.