# Cygwin inserting g when using vim in SSH session

Tags: ssh, vim, cygwin

When I SSH onto a Linux server using Cygwin and use vim in the SSH session, sometimes the first character of the file is replaced by g. Furthermore, I also see something like `:000/000/000^G` on the line that commands are entered for vim. I don't see this when I SSH from a Linux desktop to the same Linux server. Version of Cygwin is 3.1.7. Version of vim on Linux server is 8.1

When I run `echo $TERM; stty -a` on Cygwin I get the following output:

```
xterm
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = ^Z; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -tostop echoctl echoke
-flusho
```

Running the same command when I ssh onto my Linux server, I get the following output:

```
xterm
speed 9600 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

On my Linux desktop, this what I get running the same above command:

```
xterm-256color
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Is this a bug, and what is a work-around for this?

------Update (to clarify) -------------

This issue is *only* seen when I use SSH to a Linux server using Cygwin, and I use vim during the SSH session. I don't see it when I use vim in Cygwin, without SSH'ing. If I ssh from a Linux machine to the Linux server, and use vim, I don't see the issue.

Comment: Can you give the exact procedure to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: The best I can come up with is use the specific version of Cygwin, 3.1.7, in Windows 10 and ssh onto a server with vim 8.1. Then use vim to open files. Seems to happen for me 75% of the time when opening the same file over and over.

Comment: Can you try `ssh linux-server vim file` to see if you have the same problem ?

Comment: When I run `ssh e2admin@192.XXX.X.XXX vim .profile`, I don't see the issue. I just see a couple of messages saying it isn't outputting/inputting to a terminal, and then I'm in vim.

Comment: I also can't edit in vim when I run that command.

Comment: After saving the file, is the `g` also present in the saved file? Just wondering whether this is really a `g`, or perhaps `vim` tried to ring the bell, and the Control-G character happened to be displayed by a _g_.

Comment: Can you run two commands on both cygwin and Linux desktop : `echo $TERM; stty -a` and paste results ?

Comment: @user1934428, no it happens when I open things up. If I replace the g with the correct character and save, it doesn't show up.

Comment: Please add the output to your question where it can be properly formatted.

Comment: _If I replace the g with the correct character and save_ : If you do **not** replace the g and save, is the _g_ afterwards in the saved file? Does it happen only if you edit an existing file, or also when you start with an empty file? Do you see the same behaviour with other text editors (for instance `nano`)?

Comment: @user3273814 Have you tried this possibility?    
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31802751/4390071       The same problem could solved in two different ways:      1) Reinstall to older version of vim. i reinstalled to 7.4.752-1 and bug is gone.
2) Change cygwin terminal to anyone but "xterm*" (right-click on title bar -> Options... -> Terminal -> Type)

Comment: Can you try this : `ssh -t linux-server vim .profile`  ? And let me know if you still get messages.

Comment: @user1934428 If I don't replace the g, it gets saved to the file. I haven't seen it with anything but vim. I don't get the g replacing the first character if the file is empty.

Comment: @Philippe when I run that command, I get the original problem.

Comment: @O'Bieito the issue seems different enough, not to be exactly the same. (See my clarification in the question). But I suppose it is worth trying.  Changing to a Cygwin terminal other than xterm doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: I guess you need to restart Cygwin for the change to the terminal takes effect. And that's why changing the Cygwin terminal to something not xterm wasn't working. So I got it go away by changing the terminal and restarting Cygwin.

Comment: Ok, so then I added my comment as an answer in case you think it can be accepted, as it finally solved your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this possibility? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31802751/4390071

The same problem could solved in two different ways:

1. Reinstall to older version of vim. i reinstalled to 7.4.752-1 and bug is gone.
2. Change cygwin terminal to anyone but "xterm*" (right-click on title bar -> Options... -> Terminal -> Type)

Comment: As commented by OP, Cygwin has to be restarted in order for the change to take place.